# Shared Variable between Watin ApartmentState.STA Thread and parent Thread?

Tags: c#, watin

I'm trying to get Watin working in my SSIS script Task to do some automation by opening IE in a new thread, do something, find the final value and basically return/set that value in the parent thread.

So I have this for now:

```
public partial class TestWatin{

    public void Main()
    {     
        String finalValueFromWeb = "";            
        Thread runnerThread = new Thread(delegate() { getDAFValue(ref finalValueFromWeb ); });
        runnerThread.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
        runnerThread.Start();
        runnerThread.Join();
        MessageBox.Show(finalValueFromWeb);  

        //here i want to use the value of finalValueFromWeb to download a file
        //but if i try to access finalValueFromWeb the process would fail.
    }

    //do the Watin stuff here
    public  void findHiddenURL(String refObject)
    {
        //setup page controls, press search, grab the value of "hiddenURL"
        IE ie = new IE("some_webadress_to_go_to");
        ie.Visible = false;
        ie.SelectList("testID1").Option("Car").Select();
        ie.SelectList("testID2").Option("JAP").Select();
        ie.SelectList("testID3").Option("2012").Select();
        ie.Button("testSearch").Click();
        Link link = ie.Link("hiddenURL");
        ie.Close();

        //fails here?
        refObject = link.Url;            
    }
}
```

What I basically want to is for `findHiddenURL()` to find me a value which is a string containing some CSV url. I then want to use that string to download the CSV and process it.

The problem is when I try to set the value of `finalValueFromWeb` inside `findHiddenURL()` where the process fails. The Exception message says `The Object Reference is not set to an instance of an object`

Can someone please tell me how I should be going about this problem? What is the proper way of doing this type of thing? Thanks

Comment: Avoid using an object you got back from Watin after calling Close().  Get that string you need before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the variable a member of the class and try to lock it. You can use c# lock :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

```
protected string finalValueFromWeb ;

....

public void Main()
    {
        ...
        lock(finalValueFromWeb)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(finalValueFromWeb);  
        }
    }

 public  void findHiddenURL(String refObject)
    {
        ...
        lock(finalValueFromWeb)
        {
            finalValueFromWeb = link.Url;   
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion - it fails at same place - when i try to change the value of finalValueFromWeb inside findHiddenURL method the method fails!

Comment: What is the exception? You can try to debug and to see what's putting there into the variable?

Comment: I think in your case link is null when you try to access the Link.Url, can you check this?